# Can multiple consumers consume at the same time?

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I am new to Kafka . I wanted to know if multiple consumers can consume data from the topic at the same time and process them simultaneously or they are consumed and processed in batches ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kafka Consumers group themselves under a consumer group name, and each record published to a topic is delivered to one consumer instance within each subscribing consumer group. Consumer instances can be in separate processes or on separate machines.

If all the consumer instances have the same consumer group, then the records will effectively be load balanced over the consumer instances.

If all the consumer instances have different consumer groups, then each record will be broadcast to all the consumer processes.

The processing of the data can be done simultaneously or in batches based on your requirement.